# Answer migrated to comment, no alert. Why?

Tags: discussion

I wrote a short answer last night on [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/58833/how-to-calculate-how-much-house-i-can-afford) shortly before going to bed. When I got up this morning to edit the answer to add details, it had been migrated to a comment. It was a short answer, so fine, I understand.

What puzzles me is that there was no alert showing in my stackexchange inbox. Why? If this is a known issue, then it should probably be standard practice to tag the user in another comment to alert them to the change.

Answer (score 2):

There is a comment explaining it, but I'm wondering if it shouldn't have an @username in it to alert the user who posted it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was flagged, suggesting that it was more appropriate as a comment. I hit the button to do that. 
Your current answer changed the comment to a full blown answer which has already been accepted as best. 
I don't know how the alerts work in this process.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the help of a coworker who is a moderator on another SE site. It looks like there would have been an alert sent when the post was flagged as low-quality.

The moderator action of converting to a comment did delete the original post. At that point when the post was deleted, the alert of the comment from the flag was removed from the inbox.

I assume that someone felt the behavior of removing alerts when a moderator takes an action that deletes a post was desirable. It was confusing, but no big deal.